# Given a surface area, longitude and latitude, is there a formula for determining the best resolution to use with Google Tiles to map the area?

Tags: python, cartopy, vector-tiles

I'm trying to create a series of maps showing general geographic features (e.g. major roads and town names) using Cartopy and Matplotlib, but have been stumped trying to write a function to calculate the right resolution when adding the Google Tiles.

I've tried looking into how the resolution and tiles work but it's all getting a bit confusing. I was able to compute the meters per pixel given the latitude and resolution but nothing that connects to the square area that I'm shown, so I'm wondering if there is an easier way to estimate the best resolution to plot a rectangular area given:

- latitude and longitude of the centroid
- surface area of the rectangular area (in sq km)

Specifically, I want to be able to choose a resolution that looks best and shows the general landscape given the surface area being mapped and its geocoordinates.

Comment: the general answer to your title question is definitely "no". the number of tiles and the size of the display varies based on the browser & screen setup as well as what you're showing. there are tons of ways to approach this issue, and the right one for you will depend on your specific needs. if you have a specific implementation and would like a bit of guidance setting up your algorithm, feel free to post an [mre] showing us where you're stuck.

Comment: Pre-rendered tiles have a fixed resolution, you can avoid resampling/scaling the tiles by rounding you view to the closest resolution. Alternatively you can select the closest zoom-level to your chosen view/resolution, and round that either up or down.